# App to send a file from phone to phone without using network

Tags: android, file-synchronization

Let's say I want to send a file from my phone to the phone of my friend (who is physically next to me).

I can't use the telephony network nor WiFi.

Is there an app to send the file anyway, using Bluetooth/NFC if available, or QR code video (sender's screen shows video, receiver's camera records and recognizes), or even audio. Or anything faster than might be available.

Requirements:

- No network
- Reliable, using checksums where needed
- Runs on Android
- Open source

Answer (score 2):

You might wish to take a look at my list for [Filetransfer between two Android devices](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_misc#group_433) – I'm sure you'll find your candidate there. And I'm pretty sure it will be something like...

**[SuperBeam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.majedev.superbeam)**, which makes use of NFC (if available) or QR-Codes (otherwise) to connect two devices, and then uses WiFi-Direct for the transfer itself. So it's easy to connect – and much faster than Bluetooth:

[image: SuperBeam Select] [image: SuperBeam QR]
<sup>*SuperBeam* (click images for larger variants)</sup>

As the screenshots show, it's pretty easy to deal with: On the sending side, you select what to send and how to initiate the transfer – and on the target device (which also must have the app installed), you select the same connection method: either scanning a QR code, or hold the devices close to each other and use NFC.

It's possible to use *SuperBeam* on the sending side even if the target does *not* have the app installed – but that would involve a web service, and thus contradict your requirements. Speaking of which:

- **No network:** Taken literally, I had to recommend an SDCard ;) But: No internet connection required, it uses WiFi-Direct.
- **Reliable, using checksums where needed:** I don't know about the "internal handling", but all I've heard was positive feedback. So it should be reliable – however it does its job.
- **Runs on Android:** Yupp, it's an Android app.
- **Open Source:** Afraid that's the only part the app does *not* match. Moreover, I'm afraid that's the part hard to match: Though my above mentioned list covers 13 candidates currently, none of them seems to be Open Source – and I've not heard of such. Though I must admit the fact simply slipped by when I investigated on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth file transfer works for a subset of files for the rest you may need to rename the file to have an extension of .jpg, transfer it and then rename it back.

Comment: Is there an app for this?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul as Steve seems to be "temporarily out of order": A few can be found in my lists again, see [Bluetooth Fileserver](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_server_file#group_409). But BT is pretty limited, especially when it comes to bigger files (which is why I didn't even think about mentioning that). Might come in handy, though, as a fallback if one of the devices doesn't work with WiFi-Direct.